# Scala type evidences

Tags: scala, types

In scala source I can see this code:

```
@implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${From} <:< ${To}.")
sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
private[this] final val singleton_<:< = new <:<[Any,Any] { def apply(x: Any): Any = x }
// not in the <:< companion object because it is also
// intended to subsume identity (which is no longer implicit)
implicit def conforms[A]: A <:< A = singleton_<:<.asInstanceOf[A <:< A]

@implicitNotFound(msg = "Cannot prove that ${From} =:= ${To}.")
sealed abstract class =:=[From, To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
private[this] final val singleton_=:= = new =:=[Any,Any] { def apply(x: Any): Any = x }
object =:= {
    implicit def tpEquals[A]: A =:= A = singleton_=:=.asInstanceOf[A =:= A]
}
```

It's not entirely clear to me, why both these classes extend `Function1`. Wouldn't extending anything suffice?

Comment: Well, depends on what you mean by "proof". If you remove the `Function1` base type, you still have a mechanism by which a call to a given generic method will compile if and only if `A <:< B`, thereby statically *proving* the sub-type relation between `A` and `B`. However, you would not be able to use this proof inside the method body, and I think that is what was not clear to coubeatczech.

Comment: Imagine you don't know the implementation details. Somebody claims, "I know that A is a subtype of B". You ask them to give you a function `A => B`, but they say they can not. You would then assume they are lying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the time when you want to ensure that `A <:< B` (or more correctly, you want to ensure that `A <: B` using an evidence of type `A <:< B`), it is because you actually have a value of type `A` and want to be able to treat it as an instance of type `B`.

When you have a value `x: A`, proving via the presence of an implicit value that `A` is a sub-type of `B` won't magically change the type of `x` to `B`.

But for all intents and purpose `<:<` actually allows this because it is also a function that just returns its argument (it is basically the identity, with just an added - and slightly hidden - cast). 
This way when your method get passed an implicit value of type `A <:< B`, what you get is actually also a suitable implicit conversion from `A` to `B` (implicitly converting `x:A` to a value of type `B`).

In the case when you don't actually need to convert anything, well that does not really matter whether  `<:<` extends `Function1` or not.

The same rationale applies to `=:=`.

**UPDATE**: In response to "In the case of =:=, Why would I want to convert values of type A to value of type A ?":

You should first note that even in the case of `<:<` there is the same apparent contradiction: surely if `A <: B` I can treat any value of type `A` as a value of type `B` (this is pretty much the definition of sub-typing). 
Say we have the following generic method:

```
class Foo { 
  def hello() { println("hello!") } 
}
def f[T]( value: T )(implicit e: T <:< Foo){
  value.hello()
}
class Bar extends Foo
f( new Bar )
```

When compiling `f` the compiler only knows that `value` has some type `T`. 
Nothing tells the compiler that `T` will always be a sub-type of `Foo`.
So if it were not for the fact that `e: T <:< Foo` also provides an implicit conversion from `T` to `Foo`,
then the call `value.hello()` would fail because `T` is just some type that the compiler does not know 
anything about.
It is only by careful design that having an implicit value `e: T <:< Foo` in scope happens if and only if `T <: Foo`.
But the compiler has no idea of this, so from his point of view `T` and `Foo` are unrelated. 
Thus we have to provide him a way to convert values of type `T` to `Foo`, which is done by the `T <:< Foo` evidence itself.

As I said, the same rationale applies to `=:=`: having an instance of `T =:= Foo` gives no clue to the compiler about the fact 
that `T = Foo` , so the conversion must be provided to him.

Comment: In the case of `=:=`, Why would I want to convert values of type `A` to value of type `A` ?