# How does the <:< operator work in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-constraints

In Scala there's a class `<:<` that witnesses a type constraint. From `Predef.scala`:

```
  sealed abstract class <:<[-From, +To] extends (From => To) with Serializable
  private[this] final val singleton_<:< = new <:<[Any,Any] { def apply(x: Any): Any = x }
  implicit def $conforms[A]: A <:< A = singleton_<:<.asInstanceOf[A <:< A]
```

An example of how it's used is in the `toMap` method of `TraversableOnce`:

```
def toMap[T, U](implicit ev: A <:< (T, U)): immutable.Map[T, U] =
```

What I don't understand is **how this works**. I understand that `A <:< B` is syntactically equivalent to the type `<:<[A, B]`. But I don't get how the compiler can find an implicit of that type if and only if `A <: B`. I assume that the `asInstanceOf` call in the definition of `$conforms` is making this possible somehow, but how? Also, is it significant that a singleton instance of an abstract class is used, instead of just using an `object`?

Comment: I'm aware that there are a couple of other questions about this class asking what it's for, or how to use it, but not how it works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603003/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427345/

And there's an exact duplicate of this question but it was itself closed as a duplicate, in my opinion erroneously- the question it's supposedly a duplicate *of* doesn't ask how the implementation *works*:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464976/

Comment: There's also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306623/scala-type-evidences/21306762#21306762 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714609/using-scala-implicitly-for-type-equality/22717040#22717040

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Suppose we've got the following simple type hierarchy:

```
trait Foo
trait Bar extends Foo
```

We can ask for proof that `Bar` extends `Foo`:

```
val ev = implicitly[Bar <:< Foo]
```

If we run this in a console with `-Xprint:typer`, we'll see the following:

```
private[this] val ev: <:<[Bar,Foo] =
  scala.this.Predef.implicitly[<:<[Bar,Foo]](scala.this.Predef.$conforms[Bar]);
```

So the compiler has picked `$conforms[Bar]` as the implicit value we've asked for. Of course this value has type `Bar <:< Bar`, but because `<:<` is covariant in its second type parameter, this is a subtype of `Bar <:< Foo`, so it fits the bill.

(There's some magic involved here in the fact that the Scala compiler knows how to find subtypes of the type it's looking for, but it's a fairly generic mechanism and isn't too surprising in its behavior.)

Now suppose we ask for proof that `Bar` extends `String`:

```
val ev = implicitly[Bar <:< String]
```

If you turn on `-Xlog-implicits`, you'll see this:

```
<console>:9: $conforms is not a valid implicit value for <:<[Bar,String] because:
hasMatchingSymbol reported error: type mismatch;
 found   : <:<[Bar,Bar]
 required: <:<[Bar,String]
       val ev = implicitly[Bar <:< String]
                          ^
<console>:9: error: Cannot prove that Bar <:< String.
       val ev = implicitly[Bar <:< String]
                          ^
```

The compiler tries the `Bar <:< Bar` again, but since `Bar` isn't a `String`, this isn't a subtype of `Bar <:< String`, so it's not what we need. But `$conforms` is the only place the compiler can get `<:<` instances (unless we've defined our own, which would be dangerous), so it quite properly refuses to compile this nonsense.

---

To address your second question: the `<:<[-From, +To]` class is necessary because we need the type parameters for this type class to be useful. The singleton `Any <:< Any` value could just as well be defined as an object—the decision to use a `val` and an anonymous class is arguably a little simpler, but it's an implementation detail that you shouldn't ever need to worry about.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Can you add some info on why it extends `(From => To)` and implements `apply`? I assume that method is never called.

Comment: It does get used in many cases. Take the `toMap` definition, for example—[this line](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L302) wouldn't compile without an implicit conversion from `A` to `(T, U)` in scope.