# List[EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj]] => EitherT[Future, String, List[CustomObj]]

Tags: scala, scala-cats, either

How to use `sequence` function for List[EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj]] with custom class  CustomObj ? I want something like that :

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
import cats.instances.list._
import cats.syntax.traverse._
import cats.data.EitherT
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class CustomObj(int: Int)

private val fst: EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj] =
  EitherT.pure[Future, String](CustomObj(1))
private val snd: EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj] =
  EitherT.pure[Future, String](CustomObj(2))

val source: List[EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj]] = fst :: snd :: Nil

val result: EitherT[Future, String, List[CustomObj]] = source.sequence

import scala.concurrent.duration._
val res = scala.concurrent.Await.result(result.value, 1 second)
println(res) // Right(List(CustomObj(1), CustomObj(2)))
```

Every time during compile I get

```
 error: Cannot prove that EitherT[Future,String,CustomObj] <:< G[A].
```

What does it mean <:< G[A] ?

Comment: @erip [A note on sequencing](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html#a-note-on-sequencing)

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't work"?

Comment: I get : error: Cannot prove that cats.data.EitherT[Future, SomeType1, SomeType2] <:< G[A]. Actually I can't understand why it happens..

Comment: You should create a minimal example that we can copy and paste. I can't debug this without more info.

Comment: I've edited my post

Comment: scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification" .  Just add it to build.sbt or pom.xml if you use maven.
This does the trick. Now everything works fine. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an edited version, code @ https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Yaneeve/Jro89ZHwS3G23Aveanxc5A:

```
import scala.language.postfixOps
import cats.implicits._
import cats.data.EitherT
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

case class CustomObj(int: Int)

private val fst: EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj] =
  EitherT.pure[Future, String](CustomObj(1))
private val snd: EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj] =
  EitherT.pure[Future, String](CustomObj(2))

val source: List[EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj]] = fst :: snd :: Nil

val result: EitherT[Future, String, List[CustomObj]] = source.sequence

import scala.concurrent.duration._
val res = scala.concurrent.Await.result(result.value, 1 second)
println(res) // Right(List(CustomObj(1), CustomObj(2)))
```

Initially I wrote:

> Notice please that it didn't compile and produced odd compile messages
>   until I added `import
>   scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`

And that holds true, ***BUT*** your trouble did not lie there. When I went to reproduce again, I got the error you had specified. The thing that was missing is an SBT/scalac flag: `scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification"`

Comment: Thanks a lot .. but I get : 

error: 
Cannot prove that cats.data.EitherT[Future, SomeType1, SomeType2] <:< G[A].

Actually I can't understand why it happens..

Comment: What are `SomeType1` `SomeType2`? They are not in your question

Comment: it doesn't matter.. let it be :
EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj] 


The error is: Cannot prove that cats.data.EitherT[Future, String, CustomObj] <:< G[A].

Comment: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Yaneeve/Jro89ZHwS3G23Aveanxc5A - I have reworked it here slightly an I will amend my answer accordingly

Comment: I still get error: Cannot prove that EitherT[Future,String,CustomObj] <:< G[A].

What does it mean <:< G[A]. ?

Comment: Truly odd, did you add the flag and reload the project? You can see that the scastie compiles and runs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606755/how-does-the-operator-work-in-scala AND https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Predef$.html#%3C:%3C[-From,+To]extendsFrom=%3ETowithSerializable

Comment: In my project I use maven and sbt... I added this flag also to my pom.xml and it did the trick . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help :)