# How does the Scala compiler synthesize implicit evidence with `<:<`?

Tags: scala, implicits

Given this (admittedly contrived) code fragment in Scala:

```
object Main extends App {

  class X { def foo = 1 }

  def f[A](value: A)(implicit ev: A <:< X) = { value.foo }

  println(f(new X()))

}
```

What does the Scala compiler do to make this pass? I have looked at some code in `Predef` but I don't understand the implementation. Please give a detailed step by step explanation.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714609/using-scala-implicitly-for-type-equality/22717040#22717040 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306623/scala-type-evidences/21306762#21306762

Comment: Thanks @RégisJean-Gilles. I read both posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Callsite

Let's look at what the type inferencer does when you write:

```
f(new X())
```

It first has to figure out, what the template parameter `A` of `f` is. Type inference in Scala goes left to right in argument lists, so trivially (given `new X` is of type `X`), we get

```
f[X](new X)
```

Now the compiler needs to find an implicit value of type `X <:< X` (remember, `A` got resolved to `X`).

To find implicit values, the compiler looks in various places, amongst others your current scope (in which `Predef._` is imported).

The compiler then finds [`Predef.$conforms`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/525102dca81303a9549337f0fe5b714eb7b6fab1/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L425):

```
implicit def $conforms[A]: A <:< A = // some implementation
```

So this can be used to produce a `X <:< X`, by invoking it with `X` as parameter:

```
f[X](new X)(Predef.$conforms[X])
```

The actual implementation of `$conforms` does not matter as far as the type checker is concerned.

### Method Implementation

Now lets look at the implementation:

```
 def f[A](value: A)(implicit ev: A <:< X) = { value.foo }
```

Value is of type `A` (so something unknown). You want to call `foo` on `value`. Since `foo` is not defined on `A`, the compiler is looking for an implicit function (or method) that converts `A` into something that has a `foo`.

There is such a thing in scope: `ev` (`A <:< B` extends `A => B`).

Therefore, the compiler inserts an implicit conversion using `ev`:

```
ev(value).foo
```

### Small Note About Variance

As you might have noticed, `<:<` is variant in its parameters: `<:<[-From, +To]`. This can be used to generate actual subtyping evidences. Consider:

```
class A
class B extends A

val ev1: A <:< A = conforms
val ev2: B <:< A = ev1 // makes sense, works because of variance

// Also
val ev3: B <:< B = conforms
val ev4: B <:< A = ev3 // makes sense, works because of variance
```

This is notably the reason, why there is no need for a `conforms` method with two type parameters. Further, note that this behavior is specifically **not** wanted for `=:=` (since this is type equivalence), so it is invariant.

Comment: gzm0 Thanks very much. One more question, when would the variance in <:<[-From, +To] be needed (instead of just <:<[From,To], like in =:=? How to change the example to demonstrate that?

Comment: Added a small section about it.